# How do they connect? Abp, AbpZero, AbpZeroTemplate

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

It's unclear how the repositories are connected and tied together. Each git repo has a different package of cs files, with their own unique features and design schemas. Rather than a hierarchical design structure, where in my understanding or example:

**Abp**-base (free git repo), would have core essentials

**AbpZero**-paid (membership subscription to premium git repo), would add additional features into their design that would encourage others to pay for.

**AbpZeroTemplate**-demo (download from website, not git), would be a sample utilizing the paid content to push and drive sales to unlock the tool to it's full potential.

I downloaded and even paid for the different tiers, but all of the contents are all over the place. When I tried to combine them so that I could take advantage of a complete product, nothing lined up properly, and I get breakage everywhere.

How am I supposed to change the crucial schema design flaws when half of the `.proj` links to `.dll` that expect the class to be structured a certain way?

> **Example:**
> `User` is structured: "Name", "Surname". But i want it to be "Firstname", "Lastname." Some may ask, what's the difference? Just like how "Maiden name" is different from "Last name" or "Family name." Those little nuances are'nt procedural thinking. If you went to a stranger and asked *"what's your name?"* and they said "Chuck Jones," you would then ask to clarify, *"What's your first name?"*

Each git repository is running off of a different versioning number, that doesn't match with their counterpart. AbpZero is on a stable release version 5.x, and you go to GitHub for Abp and it's saying version 3.x is stable and green. And one of them is using `User<TTenant,TUser>` as a class, and the other is using `User<TUser>`. So not only am I getting mixed signals on how they're supposed to work (because git repos point to each other, and rely on .dll for continuity) but they're also not even sharing the same coding structure.

Can anybody help me merge the old and new together, or tell me the direction on how the design is being built?

Comment: Considering that the official discussion board and support forum for all concerns and questions point to stackoverflow, i feel like my question is legitimate and qualifies as one that is allowed by stackoverflow standards. Who else can answer if not the community or the creator?

Comment: ASP.NET Zero (not AbpZero) is a "complete product" built on ABP, which is a framework. AbpZeroTemplate is a free template alternative to ASP.NET Zero and also built on ABP. It makes no sense to combine them. Read the documentation on [NLayer Architecture](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture).

Comment: How does it not make sense to combine them, when you have two separate products using the same framework? That's like having a console war, but rather than being that guy that complains about one console is better than the other, i just opt for a PC and say "it does the same job as either but better."

Comment: Sorry for double posting, but the _NLayer_ isnt the discussion i'm seeking. My concern is how to combine a tool that uses the **same framework** into 1 product, instead of having two separate products that does half the job. I tried to layer the files into the same project, but the `.dll` references dont match up (even though they share the same name/source).

Comment: They are complete products on their own.

Comment: You're like trying to combine React and Angular and saying both are based on JavaScript and should be combined.

Comment: That's not how the product is marketed. AbpZero is sold as a DLC pack for the Abp framework. It's not a stand-alone product, it's an expansion pack. As pointed out previously, the template is a demo to display potential of product, while driving sales to buy the DLC to get the full service. Not everything is included, and they are two separate items.

Comment: Though my understanding of the technology behind React and Angular is poor, i'll stick with my analogy of a console war, and incorporate the best of both worlds into a PC unit. The ability to mix and match, as well as upgrade where technology needs improvements or performance increase (not to mention flexibility to adapt the peripherals from the consoles). Why fight over which is better, when i can have both in one product? Did you read the **why** edit i made?

Comment: Nobody said ASP.NET Zero (again, not AbpZero) is a DLC pack or an expansion pack. It's marketed as a stand-alone product — more accurately, a base solution. Are you living in your own world?

Comment: Also, you're straying away from the question. The product is lines of code. It's not impossible to combine the two. I'm not asking why i should or shouldn't. I'm asking how, because i'm missing information locked behind a paid-subscription wall that expired on me. I would use a forum if i could, but this is the only outlet. Please submit an answer if you have one, everything i've mentioned and written is perfectly reasonable, and not a complicated demand. Clearly we're allowed to construct the files however we please, hence why we're given access to git repositories.

Comment: this question has nothing to with programming. it's a discussion that has no true answer. what kind of answer are you expecting for setting as solution?

Comment: Read first comment and then read the TLDR. It's not about programming, it's about a product that requested all concerns to be posted on this site.

Comment: but this platform is a wrong place to share your ideas about a technology. but anyway i wish moderation would keep this post because there's an already rich answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to ASP.NET Boilerplate

1. ASP.NET Core is a web framework developed by Microsoft, as you know. There are plenty different applications based on it.
2. ABP is an application framework on top of ASP.NET Core (and MVC 5.x but it's a different story - I skip). It tries to help real life applications on top of ASP.NET Core. It has many features like advanced authorization, background jobs, javascript proxies, DDD infrastructure and so on.. This is completely free and developed on Github: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate Thousands of developers are actively using it to build their applications.

ABP framework does not provide a User Interface itself, but provides the infrastructure. So, you should create an empty ASP.NET Core application, add nuget packages, configure the framework and modules, create a UI layout and some basic pages to start your development. This is also a time consuming work. That's why we have created "STARTUP TEMPLATES". There are two startup template:

(A) A free & open source startup template can be downloaded here: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates (It just gets the code from https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template and renames solution for you). This is a simple startup template (but more powerful then ASP.NET Core's standard template when you make File > New Project).

(B) A PAID startup template, which becomes the product on https://aspnetzero.com/. This template has much much more features on top of the framework. You can see all on its web site. Since it's a paid product, the Github repository is private and only available to paid customers.

You either start with template (A) or template (B). You CAN NOT combine them. I believe it's very obvious. For instance. Microsoft provides different startup templates for ASP.NET Core: One of them is Angular, one of them is Razor Pages, one of them is empty... and so on.. So, you select one of them based on your needs.

Both of (A) and (B) templates work on the ABP framework and adds via nuget packages (it's already combined/integrated).

So, after this explanation, I believe no one would even think how to combine them.

> How am i supposed to change the crucial schema design flaws when half of the .proj links to .dll that expect the class to be structured a certain way?

When you use a framework or a pre-build solution, you have significant advantages. However, there is nothing in the World that has only advantages. Every solution/framework/library will come with its own limitations, you like or not.

With that in mind.. Despite of other vendors, we provide the FULL SOURCE CODE! User class or another schema class is not inside a CLOSED/SECRET DLL. They are on nuget packages and are open source as I described before. They are framework code. If you want to change the framework code it's always possible. Just download the ABP framework on [Github repository](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate), include into your solution, remove nuget packages and add project references. Then you can freely change the `User` class. Source code is open & here:

- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.ZeroCore/Authorization/Users/AbpUser.cs
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/src/Abp.Zero.Common/Authorization/Users/AbpUserBase.cs

> Each git repository is running off of a different versioning number

Why we follow the same version numbers for different products those are released and developed separately? Does Microsoft have same version number for all products?

> I wish i had enough money as the next guy to afford throwing around $1600 a year just to resolve issues with poorly documented code, but sadly i do not

There are thousands of customers paid it and they are happy about our product and they are renewing their licenses to be able to access to latest source code after 1 year. If anybody wants a refund, we always provide a money back without any question. Refund request ratio is smaller than 0.5% because developers love our framework and product.

> My membership expired while i was resolving conflict issues with the code, and i immediately lost the ability to use git repo connected to that service

You can contact info@aspnetzero.com and request the latest version of the code (when the time your license expired). We always help to our customers about that. It would be better if you had contact with us.

Comment: It was a legitimate question and my criticism played a key role in my confusion. The naming of repositories werent clear or documented that labeled which is which. I've spent many hours clicking links after links under both websites (abp, git, abpzero) to resolve a lot of my issues that i've been struggling with. The versioning number wasnt a criticism, it was a me just being thoroughly confused looking for directions and receiving mixed signals. I downloaded so many different files from your site, asking for another version wouldnt have helped to resolve the underlying issues...

Comment: I never said i wasnt satisfied with your product (which is why i never bothered asking for a refund), i merely expressed that it wasn't straight-forward and easy to use as it was advertised. (Which is why we're here on SO)

Comment: Thanks for your additional explanations. Easiness depends.. But most of the people find it very straightforward to work with as we get feedback. If you had confusion about the projects, you could/can always ask. We answer to even general programming/design questions independent of our products. And it's not late. If you want to get help, please write to info@aspnetzero.com. We can also provide the latest source code before your license expired.

Comment: Can you help explain the difference between `#2` and letter `(A)`? How is the Template different from the Framework? _Why i ask:_ I have multiple copies of different files, and there all over the place on my hard drive; a few of them combined and merged into each other, and go back to the reason i posted this SO. I want to make _[simple]_ changes to the framework, and some light additions to the core mechanic of how things function. But as i start making any changes, everything stops working... I havent had a working copy since i downloaded the files to PC (all my changes break).

Comment: Framework is deployed to nuget and used by referencing. You normally don't change its source code, just use and configure it. Just like ASP.NET Core itself. Did you ever changes ASP.NET Core's source code. Microsoft develops it, you just update nuget packages when they release a new version.
Template is a Visual Studio solution with pre-coded functionality. You download it, open in VS and run. Full source code is in your computer and you change it freely. Templates are not automatically upgradeable as their nature.

Comment: I want to **modify** the framework, so referencing nugets doesnt give me the ability to make changes to how the mechanics of the framework is supposed to function. Both in your answer and my many comments (as well as in the question), the `(A)` and `(B)` reference the framework `#2`. I dont want to use nugets, i want to combine the framework to the downloadable _whatever we call it_ (because DLC/Template arnt terms that others can follow) and make one change to **everything**. When i combine the framework to the templates, i get errors... _that_ is the question.

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, if i wrote a code and called it `Acme.Phonebook` and it was based off of the Abp framework, and i called it a "template." Then attempted to use the same "MyCompany" template written about in `(A)`. Are you telling me that the two of them could never be combined into one project? `You either start with template (A) or template (B). You CAN NOT combine them. I believe it's very obvious.` <- i don't see how it's very obvious if they do two different things, and they use the same technology. Kinda like jQuery & JS, where one uses the other, but can still have multiples...